# How to programmatically pin a post to a Facebook feed?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Does the Facebook Graph API allow you to "PIN" a post to a the top of a groups' feed? I'm unable to find any documentation on it.

Specifically, we're looking to enable this functionality for group admins (so they can pin something to the top of a groups' feed)

Answer (score 0):

Having gone through the docs, I'm not sure programmatic pinning is possible, but someone from FB should vouch for it

You could alternatively star your posts like this

```
POST /<post_id>/ with param timeline_visibility = starred
```